Why do we use __init__ and self together every time while using classes in Python?
I'm currently learning Python OOP with concepts of methods, data hiding, encapsulation, inheritance, constructor, deconstructor, polymorphism and overloading but why it takes self every time while defining those methods is a wonder to me.

We use init to initialize an instance of a class, and self refers to the instance itself, allowing us to set or access its attributes. Together, they ensure that each instance has its own unique data and behavior.
